# Is it possible to extract a intermediate layer of ResNet and make feature map which will be used as input of Faster RCNN?

Tags: computer-vision, resnet, vision

I'm wondering whether is it possible to extract a intermediate layer of ResNet and make feature map which will be used as input of Faster RCNN. I want the same size of feature map from original output of ResNet-101.
Will it be possible and how to do it?

As my expectation it might be possible, but I need confidence in this problem.